# How to extract data from HTML page source of (a tab within) a webpage?

Tags: java, android, html, ajax, jsoup

I have tried several solutions specified in other answers, like experimenting with different user agents (Chrome, safari etc), and getting HTML directly using HTTPClient and BufferedReader, but none of them work. How do I make the Android output similar as a web output?
Here is the web output I am looking for; (View page source of https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL for full output - this basically contains the AJAX tab **named "Quarterly" which contains a table**. I need to get that data, but the Android HTML source doesn't have it but the web source does.)

```
root.App.main = {"context":{"dispatcher":{"stores":{"PageStore":{"currentPageName":"quote","currentRenderTargetId":"default","pagesConfigRaw":{"base":{"quote":{"layout":{"bundleName":"yahoodotcom-layout.TwoColumnLayout","name":"TwoColumnLayout","config":{"enableHeaderCollapse":true,"Header":{"isFixed":true,"uhContainerClasses":"Bgi($uhGrayGradient)","navContainerClasses":"Bgi($navrailGrayGradient) Bxsh($navrailShadow) Pos(r) hasScrolled_Bxsh(headerShadow) Panel-open_Bxsh(headerShadow)","navTransitionClasses":"HideNavrail_Translate3d(0,-46px,0) Panel-open_Translate3d(0,-46px,0)","secondaryNavContainerClasses":"hasScrolled_Bdbw(0px) Bxsh($navrailShadow)","height":135},"fetchNewAttribution":true},"meta":{"property":{"twitter:site":"@YahooFinance"}}},"meta":{"property":{"twitter:site":"@YahooFinance","fb:pages":"90376669494"}},"regions":{"SecondaryNav":[{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"SecondaryNav","config":{"ui":{"enableRelativeUrl":true}},"props":{"key":"SecondaryNav-0-SecondaryNav","id":"SecondaryNav-0-SecondaryNav"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Overlay":[{"bundleName":"react-lightbox","name":"Lightbox","props":{"key":"Overlay-0-Lightbox","id":"Overlay-0-Lightbox"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"Null","props":{"key":"Overlay-1-Null","id":"Overlay-1-Null"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"Null","props":{"key":"Overlay-2-Null","id":"Overlay-2-Null"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Lead":[{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"FinanceHeader","props":{"className":"Bxz(bb) H(100%) Pos(r) Maw($newGridWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mstart(a) Mend(a) Px(20px) My(10px)","showAds":true,"adsConfig":{"positions":["FB2A","FB2B","FB2C","FB2D"]},"key":"Lead-0-FinanceHeader","id":"Lead-0-FinanceHeader"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"tdv2-applet-featurebar","name":"FeatureBar","config":{"ui":{"container_classnames":"W(100%) Bxz(bb) Bdrs(2px) Mb(10px) Maw($maxModuleWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mx(a)","prerender":{"enabled":true,"renderTargetId":"modal"}},"site":"finance"},"props":{"key":"Lead-1-FeatureBar","id":"Lead-1-FeatureBar"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteHeader","props":{"key":"Lead-2-QuoteHeader","id":"Lead-2-QuoteHeader"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteNav","props":{"key":"Lead-3-QuoteNav","id":"Lead-3-QuoteNav"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Col1":[{"bundleName":"td-ads","name":"Ad","props":{"pos":"LDRB","style":{"marginBottom":"8px","paddingTop":"0px","marginLeft":"auto","marginRight":"auto","textAlign":"center","lineHeight":"0px","position":"relative","zIndex":"5"},"key":"Col1-0-Ad","id":"Col1-0-Ad"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"Quote.financials","name":"Financials","props":{"key":"Col1-1-Financials","id":"Col1-1-Financials"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"AdUnitWithTdAds","props":{"className":"ad-foot","positions":["FOOT"],"key":"Col1-2-AdUnitWithTdAds","id":"Col1-2-AdUnitWithTdAds"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"AdUnitWithTdAds","props":{"className":"ad-fsrvy","positions":["FSRVY"],"key":"Col1-3-AdUnitWithTdAds","id":"Col1-3-AdUnitWithTdAds"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Col2":[{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"ExtPromoButton","props":{"className":"btn Bds(s) Bdc($c-fuji-grey-c) Bdrs(4px) Bgc($white) Bdw(1px) Bgc($ExtButtonHov):h C($white):h C($ExtButtonHov) Cur(p) Fz(s) Fw(b) H(44px) Lh(40px) Mb(20px) Ta(c) Td(n) W(100%)","sec":"ext-promo-all-mkt-submit","titleId":"EXTENSION_PROMO_TITLE","url":"https:\u002F\u002Fchrome.google.com\u002Fwebstore\u002Fdetail\u002Fdoojmkhhplhicnghmafjbhncmgjiohma","enabled":true,"key":"Col2-0-ExtPromoButton","id":"Col2-0-ExtPromoButton"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteModule","props":{"type":"eventPromo","key":"Col2-1-QuoteModule","id":"Col2-1-QuoteModule"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"td-ads","name":"ComboAd","props":{"adparseStyle":{"marginBottom":"20px"},"finishedStyle":{"marginBottom":"20px"},"children":[{"bundleName":"td-ads","name":"Ad","props":{"pos":"LREC"}},{"bundleName":"td-ads","name":"Ad","props":{"pos":"MON"}}],"serverHeight":true,"key":"Col2-2-ComboAd","id":"Col2-2-ComboAd"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteModule","props":{"type":"similarCompanies","key":"Col2-3-QuoteModule","id":"Col2-3-QuoteModule"},"initMode":{"deferRender":true},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteModule","props":{"type":"earningsChart","key":"Col2-4-QuoteModule","id":"Col2-4-QuoteModule"},"initMode":{"deferRender":true},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteModule","props":{"type":"financialsChart","key":"Col2-5-QuoteModule","id":"Col2-5-QuoteModule"},"initMode":{"deferRender":true},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"react-finance",..."}}}};
```

Here is the Android output I get;

```
(root.App.main = {"context":{"dispatcher":{"stores":{"PageStore":{"currentPageName":"quote","currentRenderTargetId":"default","pagesConfigRaw":{"base":{"quote":{"layout":{"bundleName":"yahoodotcom-layout.TwoColumnLayout","name":"TwoColumnLayout","config":{"enableHeaderCollapse":true,"Header":{"isFixed":true,"uhContainerClasses":"Bgi($uhGrayGradient)","navContainerClasses":"Bgi($navrailGrayGradient) Bxsh($navrailShadow) Pos(r) hasScrolled_Bxsh(headerShadow) Panel-open_Bxsh(headerShadow)","navTransitionClasses":"HideNavrail_Translate3d(0,-46px,0) Panel-open_Translate3d(0,-46px,0)","secondaryNavContainerClasses":"hasScrolled_Bdbw(0px) Bxsh($navrailShadow)","height":135},"fetchNewAttribution":true},"meta":{"property":{"twitter:site":"@YahooFinance"}}},"meta":{"property":{"twitter:site":"@YahooFinance","fb:pages":"90376669494"}},"regions":{"SecondaryNav":[{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"SecondaryNav","config":{"ui":{"enableRelativeUrl":true}},"props":{"key":"SecondaryNav-0-SecondaryNav","id":"SecondaryNav-0-SecondaryNav"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Overlay":[{"bundleName":"react-lightbox","name":"Lightbox","props":{"key":"Overlay-0-Lightbox","id":"Overlay-0-Lightbox"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"Null","props":{"key":"Overlay-1-Null","id":"Overlay-1-Null"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"Null","props":{"key":"Overlay-2-Null","id":"Overlay-2-Null"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Lead":[{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"FinanceHeader","props":{"className":"Bxz(bb) H(100%) Pos(r) Maw($newGridWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mstart(a) Mend(a) Px(20px) My(10px)","showAds":true,"adsConfig":{"positions":["FB2A","FB2B","FB2C","FB2D"]},"key":"Lead-0-FinanceHeader","id":"Lead-0-FinanceHeader"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"tdv2-applet-featurebar","name":"FeatureBar","config":{"ui":{"container_classnames":"W(100%) Bxz(bb) Bdrs(2px) Mb(10px) Maw($maxModuleWidth) Miw($minGridWidth) Miw(a)!--tab768 Miw(a)!--tab1024 Mx(a)","prerender":{"enabled":true,"renderTargetId":"modal"}},"site":"finance"},"props":{"key":"Lead-1-FeatureBar","id":"Lead-1-FeatureBar"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteHeader","props":{"key":"Lead-2-QuoteHeader","id":"Lead-2-QuoteHeader"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteNav","props":{"key":"Lead-3-QuoteNav","id":"Lead-3-QuoteNav"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Col1":[{"bundleName":"td-ads","name":"Ad","props":{"pos":"LDRB","style":{"marginBottom":"8px","paddingTop":"0px","marginLeft":"auto","marginRight":"auto","textAlign":"center","lineHeight":"0px","position":"relative","zIndex":"5"},"key":"Col1-0-Ad","id":"Col1-0-Ad"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"Quote.financials","name":"Financials","props":{"key":"Col1-1-Financials","id":"Col1-1-Financials"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"AdUnitWithTdAds","props":{"className":"ad-foot","positions":["FOOT"],"key":"Col1-2-AdUnitWithTdAds","id":"Col1-2-AdUnitWithTdAds"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"react-finance","name":"AdUnitWithTdAds","props":{"className":"ad-fsrvy","positions":["FSRVY"],"key":"Col1-3-AdUnitWithTdAds","id":"Col1-3-AdUnitWithTdAds"},"isPageComposite":true}],"Col2":[{"bundleName":"td-app-finance","name":"ExtPromoButton","props":{"className":"btn Bds(s) Bdc($c-fuji-grey-c) Bdrs(4px) Bgc($white) Bdw(1px) Bgc($ExtButtonHov):h C($white):h C($ExtButtonHov) Cur(p) Fz(s) Fw(b) H(44px) Lh(40px) Mb(20px) Ta(c) Td(n) W(100%)","sec":"ext-promo-all-mkt-submit","titleId":"EXTENSION_PROMO_TITLE","url":"https:\u002F\u002Fchrome.google.com\u002Fwebstore\u002Fdetail\u002Fdoojmkhhplhicnghmafjbhncmgjiohma","enabled":true,"key":"Col2-0-ExtPromoButton","id":"Col2-0-ExtPromoButton"},"isPageComposite":true},{"bundleName":"QuotePage","name":"QuoteModule","props":{"type":"eventPromo","key":"Col2-1-QuoteModule","id":"Col2-1-QuoteModule"},"isPageComposite":true}
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks. 
My code;

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(requestURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.43")
                .timeout(600000).get();
        Elements tableDivs = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", myClassName);
        Elements scriptTags = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
        for (Element script : scriptTags) {
            //System.out.println(script.data());
            Log.e("ONE", script.data());
        }
```

Comment: I would not parse the HTML, very probably the table data is fetched as JSON using Ajax. Just use chrome debug, network tab and check what XHR request provides the data to the table. I would do in this way...

Comment: What's the value of `myClassName`?

Comment: My class name is "class", "Lh(1.7) W(100%) M(0)"

Comment: I prefer using the select method for getting tables and rows like: `Element table = doc2.select("table").get(0);
        List<Element> tableRows = table.select("tr");`. Table data is within "td" and extraction can be made with `.text()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo Finance redirects to guce.oath.com, which informs us about the use of cookies and other data, and requires to click 'accept' before providing the content. We can observe that also in a browser if we clear the cokies and refresh the page.

We could scrape the link from guce.oath.com, but I've noticed that the final URL has a `guccounter=2` parameter, and if we use that URL we can get the required response.

```
String requestURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL&guccounter=2";
String userAgent = "My UAString";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(requestURL).userAgent(userAgent).get();
```

Since the data is not HTML but JavaScript code, we can't parse it with `jsoup`, but we can use regular expressions.

```
Elements scriptTags = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
String re = "root\\.App\\.main\\s*\\=\\s*(.*?);\\s*\\}\\(this\\)\\)\\s*;";
String data = null;

for (Element script : scriptTags) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script.html());

    if (matcher.find()) {
        data = matcher.group(1);
        break;
    }
}
```

The `data` string should contain the dictionary from the JavaScript code, which is a valid json string that can be parsed with `JSONObject`.

---

On Android Studio however, there are no redirects as far sa I can tell. I've tried with several user-agent strings, but it seems that the page loads directly. Still, the JavaScript dictionary that contains the data is present, and we can extract it, and parse it with `JSONObject`.

Code for Android Studio:

```
String requestURL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/financials?p=AAPL";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36 OPR/56.0.3051.43";
String row = "totalRevenue";

try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(requestURL).userAgent(userAgent).get();
    String html = doc.html();
    //Log.d("html", html);

    Elements scriptTags = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
    String re = "root\\.App\\.main\\s*\\=\\s*(.*?);\\s*\\}\\(this\\)\\)\\s*;";

    for (Element script : scriptTags) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script.html());

        if (matcher.find()) {
            String data = matcher.group(1);
            //Log.d("data", data);

            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(data);
            JSONArray table = getTable(jo);
            //Log.d("table", table.toString());

            String[] tableRow = getRow(table, row);
            String values = TextUtils.join(", ", tableRow);
            Log.d("values", values);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("err", "err", e);
}
```

This should parse the data and select the 'Total Revenue' values. The `getTable` and `getRow` methods I used:

```
private JSONArray getTable(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
    JSONArray table = (JSONArray) json.getJSONObject("context")
            .getJSONObject("dispatcher")
            .getJSONObject("stores")
            .getJSONObject("QuoteSummaryStore")
            .getJSONObject("incomeStatementHistoryQuarterly")
            .getJSONArray("incomeStatementHistory");
    return table;
}

private String[] getRow(JSONArray table, String name) throws JSONException {
    String[] values = new String[table.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jo = table.getJSONObject(i);
        if (jo.has(name)) {
            jo = jo.getJSONObject(name);
            values[i] = jo.has("longFmt") ? jo.get("longFmt").toString() : "-";
        } else {
            values[i] = "-";
        }
    }
    return values;
}

private String[] getDates(JSONArray table) throws JSONException {
    String[] values = new String[table.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
        values[i] = table.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("endDate")
                .get("fmt").toString();
    }
    return values;
}
```

---

I think the best way to get the table data is to map each html row name to a json key. Furthermore, the main table has five sub-tables, so we could map each nested table to the rows it contains.

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> getTableNames() {
    final Map<String, String> revenue = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
        { put("Total Revenue", "totalRevenue"); }
        { put("Cost of Revenue", "costOfRevenue"); }
        { put("Gross Profit", "grossProfit"); }
    };
    final Map<String, String> operatingExpenses = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {
        { put("Research Development", "researchDevelopment"); }
        { put("Selling General and Administrative", "sellingGeneralAdministrative"); }
        { put("Non Recurring", "nonRecurring"); }
        { put("Others", "otherOperatingExpenses"); }
        { put("Total Operating Expenses", "totalOperatingExpenses"); }
        { put("Operating Income or Loss", "operatingIncome"); }
    };
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> allTableNames = new LinkedHashMap<String, Map<String, String>>() {
        { put("Revenue", revenue); }
        { put("Operating Expenses", operatingExpenses); }

    };
    return allTableNames;
}
```

We can use this map to select a single cell, for example the 'Total Revenue' of 6/30/2018 (which is on the first row and column),

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsData);
JSONArray table = getTable(jo);

Map<String, Map<String, String>> tableNames = getTableNames();
String totalRevenueKey = tableNames.get("Revenue").get("Total Revenue");
String[] totalRevenueValues = getRow(table, totalRevenueKey);
String value = totalRevenueValues[0];
```

or we could iterate over the table names and build a list or string, containing all the table data.

```
List<String> tableData = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, Map<String, String>> tableNames = getTableNames();
String[] dates = getDates(table);

for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> tableEntry : tableNames.entrySet()) {
    tableData.add(tableEntry.getKey());
    tableData.addAll(Arrays.asList(dates));

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> row : tableEntry.getValue().entrySet()) {
        String[] tableRow = getRow(table, row.getValue());
        tableData.add(row.getKey());
        for (String column: tableRow) {
            tableData.add(column);
        }
    }
}
String tableDataString = TextUtils.join(", ", tableData);
```

I've tried to match the html table as much as possible, so the the `tableData` list and the resulting string is formated as "table name, date,date,date,date" and "row name, price,price,price,price", but it may be best to include only the numbers. (in this case we should add only `tableRow` items to to `tableData`)

Comment: Very nice solution! I added `&amp;guccounter=2` at the end of the url and it worked. When navigating with a browser I get `_guc_consent_skip=xxxxxxx` at the end of the url.. not sure what impact it has.

Comment: The main confusing portion for me is that I'm still unsure whether I'm creating payload in the right way. For example,  I found them in dev tools like `callCount=1`, `c0-param0=number:2` and so on but I modified them to be like `'callCount':'1'` and `'c0-param0':'number:2'`.  I never found payload having ***=*** sign between key and value instead of ***:***

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, I am trying to do the same for Cash Flow Stmt at https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/cash-flow?p=AAPL - using ( .getJSONObject("dispatcher")
                .getJSONObject("stores")
                .getJSONObject("QuoteSummaryStore")
                .getJSONObject("cashflowStatementHistory")
                .getJSONArray("cashflowStatements");) 
trying to extract `trailingFreeCashFlow` - 
BUT, it keeps saying "No value for trailingFreeCashFlow"
Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey @Zac1, unfortunately I don't have much spare time these days, to ivestigate this issue. I may take a look at the end of the week, but why don't you just post a new question?

Comment: Hey @t.m.adam, did you get some time to take a look at this? I am trying to find the best way to extract the `trailingFreeCashFlow` value from the Cash Flow statement link. How do I find the right structure for the JSON object? Thanks!

Comment: @Zac1 No, sorry, I don't think I can help, not any time soon.

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam. I posted the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095236/how-to-extract-a-value-from-the-yahoo-finance-cash-flow-statement-with-java-and

Comment: @Zac1 Good luck!

Comment: Hi @t.m.adam, thanks again for your wonderful solution. It looks like something changed on Yahoo Finance and this code isn't working anymore. Do you have any tips on how to go about troubleshooting this? Thank you.